# Drupal Webform View Form Submitted data to user

Tags: webforms

I want my users to view their submitted data after submission to let them know what they submitted. 
How can I do this? 
Please help!!

Answer (score 1):

On your webform submission settings on

[image]

scroll down, then check **"Allow users to view a submission using a secure token?
"**

[image]

then as it has been mentioned there

> Allow users to view a submission using a secure token If checked users
>   will be able to view a submission using the webform submission's URL
>   appended with the submission's (secure) token. The 'tokenized' URL to
>   view a submission will be available when viewing a submission's
>   information and can be inserted into an email using the
>   [webform_submission:view-url] token.